# How do I add numbers to the end of a string to get 8 characters python

Tags: python, loops

I know this is a very simple question for anyone who knows python, but I need to know how to take a name like JOHN and use a loop to keep adding "1" until it reaches 8 characters.
AKA JOHN1111

Edit: Thank you all so much for all the different ways to complete this. I am new to python and certainly new to this website.

Comment: share code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop.

```
s = 'JOHN'
if len(s) < 8:
    s = s + '1'*(8-len(s))
```

If you really like loops:

```
s = 'JOHN'
while len(s) < 8:
    s += '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

string has a method for that: [str.ljust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust)

```
>>> t="JOHN"
>>> t.ljust(8,"1")
'JOHN1111'
```

Answer (score 0):

To do such a thing, simply create a while loop that adds a custom character to a string while the string is not of a certain length:

```py
def pad_string(string, length, character = ' '):
    while len(string) < length:
        string += character
    return string
```

Or, the more "pythonic" method for loop method:

```py
def pad_string(string, length, character = ' '):
    if len(string) > length:
        return string
    for character_number in range(length - len(string)):
        string += character
    return string
```

Usage:

```py
pad_string('JOHN', 8, '1') # 'JOHN1111'
pad_string('JOHN', 2, '1') # 'JOHN'
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using `len()` you can get the length of the word.
- subtract `8` from it.
- If result is `0` that no need to do anything. If not add `1` to it and repeat it using `(*)` until `8` character.

---

```
 name = 'JOHN'
    if len(name) < 8  :
        name = name + '1' * (8-len(name))
    print(name)
```